# value-initialization of a const member reference

Tags: c++, reference

I am looking at code of the following form:

```
class foo
{
  public:
    foo() {}

  //...
};

class bar
{
  public:
    bar() : ref() {}

  private:
    const foo &ref;
};
```

Is initializing a reference using a temporary in this way correct? I know that it is possible to initialize a const reference that's a local variable with a temporary, and that doing so extends the lifetime of the temporary, e.g.

```
const foo &tmp = funcThatReturnsByValue(); //OK
```

However, one of the answers to the related [initialize reference in initialization list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232226/initialize-reference-in-initialization-list) suggests that there is a difference between "short-lived" and "long-lived" references, and that initializing `ref` as above is undefined behavior (even though `ref` is a `const` reference).

12.2.5 in the standard says, in part, "A temporary bound to a reference member in a constructor's ctor-initializer persists until the constructor exits." Is that describing this situation?

Comment: Could you fix your code so that it actually involves a temporary?

Comment: ref() doesn't bind ref to a temporary instance of foo? Sorry if my terminology is imprecise... I'm doing my best to understand this code snippet.

Comment: Maybe this comment is worthless (I don't know the context you're looking at this code in), but the problem disappears if `ref` is a pointer. The point is that references cannot be value-initialized, but pointers can (they get zero-initialized). Moreover, most compilers (at least MSVC) issue a warning for being unable to generate a default assignment operator. As a guideline, whenever you want a reference member, you want actually a pointer...

Comment: The extension of the temporary's lifetime doesn't seem to be so dependable, after all: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604206/c-constant-reference-lifetime. It seems to be concocted in order to allow temporaries created during type conversions to work correctly, but isn't intended for other uses.

Comment: @rwong:  What do you mean it's not "so dependable?"  It is dependable, but only under two circumstances, both of which are described in the question to which you've linked.

Comment: @James McNellis: the rule only applies when the result is a true temporary *of the caller* (hence the reason the asker names the function `funcThatReturnsByValue()` ) If the function returns by reference (or other stuff) instead of by value, then it is a temporary whose lifetime is controlled by something else (such as the called function) and would have been destroyed before it is returned. So, *temporary* has a narrow meaning, and is not apparent to people outside the C++ compiler circle. It also would not be apparent to any code reviewers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code is ill-formed.  You can't default initialize or value initialize a reference.

If you actually had an expression inside of  `ref()`, then yes, 12.2.5 would apply and the temporary would be destroyed when the constructor exits.

Comment: You'd think, but I can't get GCC 4.3.4 to actually do that.

Answer (score 2):

Your example isn't creating a temporary - to do that you need to change to:

```
    bar() : ref(foo()) {}
```

Now you're binding the reference to a temporary, and that temporary object will be destroyed at the end of the constructor. Your reference will be invalid, and that is Not A Good Thing.

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you want to do is:

```
bar() : ref(foo()) {}
```

but don't naively think that the lifetime of a temporary is extended until there's a reference to it. No, it actually is not. So, whether const or not, you sould initialize the reference with a normal object.